# What command combo at terminal will output a list of directories with human-readable sizes?

Tags: terminal, command-line, uti

I'd like to open Terminal.app and **enter a command like:**

`my-macbook-pro:~ my-username$ ls -lh`

Instead of seeing the size of the folders in bytes that are in my current working directory, I'd like to see size of the folders, including all of their contents like so:

`drwxr-xr-x  7 my-username  staff   100Gi Dec 20 19:38 my-huge-project-folder`

`drwxr-xr-x  3 my-username  staff   80Gi Dec 27 14:15 my-slightly-smaller-project-folder`

Is there a command I can type that will yield similar output above?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In order to see a list of folders with sizes you can use the **du** command.

To make the sizes human readable use the **-h** option

To make sum the size of child folders use the **-s** option (may take some time to run depending on the contents).

> ```
> du -hs *
> ```

Here is an (uninteresting) example of the output.

```
   0B   Desktop
 632K   Documents
 356K   Downloads
  76M   Library
   0B   Movies
   0B   Music
 4.0K   Pictures
   0B   Public
  40K   Sites
```

Comment: @g you need more music… ;)

Comment: @martin - Or a faster computer... I ran it on a dummy account because I got impatient waiting for the results on my account!

Comment: That will only count files you have access to read. Add sudo for a true count, especially if you are measuring outside your home folder.

Comment: I like to add -c (du -shc *) to get a nice total at the end too.